# Timezone differences with GMT causing hours to change?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Below is my input date string format:

```
2025-08-08T15%3A41%3A46
```

I have to convert above string date in the format as shown below:

```
Fri Aug 08 15:41:46 GMT-07:00 2025
```

And I got below code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateParser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.US);
String decodedDate = URLDecoder.decode("2025-08-08T15%3A41%3A46", "UTF-8");
Date date = dateParser.parse(decodedDate);

//Decode the given date and convert to Date object
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-07:00"));

System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

And this is what it prints out on the console. I am not sure why it prints different hour value as compared to what I have above in the desired output. It should print out `15` but it is printing `03`.

```
Fri Aug 08 03:41:46 GMT-07:00 2025
```

I am not sure what is the reason why hours are getting changed because of timezone difference with GMT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the same time except in the first format you are using "HH" for hour that is "Hour in day (0-23)" and second format uses "hh" that is "Hour in am/pm (1-12)".

Answer (score 0):

As [the other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44122419/642706) correctly states, your formatting pattern used incorrect characters.

Let's look at an alternative modern approach.

## ISO 8601

Your input string, once decoded to restore the COLON characters, is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
URLDecoder.decode("2025-08-08T15%3A41%3A46", "UTF-8")
```

> 2025-08-08T15:41:46

## Using java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) by default when parsing/generating strings.

Your input string lacks any indication of offset-from-UTC or time zone. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2025-08-08T15:41:46" )
```

> ldt.toString(): 2025-08-08T15:41:46

If you know the intended time zone, assign a `ZoneId` to produce a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

> zdt.toString(): 2025-08-08T15:41:46-04:00[America/Montreal]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: I am still working with java 7 and cannot switch to Java8. With that in mind what is the best approach then and get the same output as I needed?

Comment: @david Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Produced by the same team that built java.time and Joda-Time.  Well worth the bother of adding a library to your project. The legacy classes are wretched.